# FactoryGirl: not-null constraint violation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

trying to create place instance with `FactoryGirl.create(:place)` but got the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:place)
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "town_city" violates not-null constraint
   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 2017-07-14 13:32:41.246627, 2017-07-14 13:32:41.246627, 51.476900, 0.000010, Greenwich Observatory, Greenwich, London, null, 24849 Lesch Garden, null, null, null, MF4 1FO, null, null, null, null, 1, null, f).
   : INSERT INTO "places" ("created_at", "geocode_address", "latitude", "longitude", "postcode", "region_id", "street_address", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"
 # ./spec/requests/api/v1/events_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Can't figure out why, because in my factory I set town_city explicitly:

Place factory:

```
factory :place, traits: [:pageable] do
  town_city 'my hardcoded value'
  latitude { rand(50.0...53.0) }
  longitude { rand(-2.0...2.0) }
  street_address { Faker::Address.street_address }
  postcode { Faker::AddressUK.postcode }
  association :region, factory: :region
end
```

Page & Pageable trait:

```
trait :pageable do
  association :page, strategy: :build
end

factory :page do
  sequence(:title) { |n| "#{Faker::Product.product_name}-#{n}" }
  association :user
  association :cover_image, factory: :image
  telephone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
  description { generate :paragraphs_seq }
end
```

Region:

```
factory :region do
  level 'area'
end
```

Any ideas what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had **before_validation** hook in my Place model, that was trying to reset *town_city* using Region fields data. So I guess I have to modify my Region factory